# Uniform distribution using C++

Tags: c++

I have two variables `R` and `S`. I defined them as `int R[1000]` and `int S[100000]`. `R` will hold the values from `0` to `999`. Now, I want the `R` values to be uniformly distributed in `S` (`100000` values ). The number of entries in `S` should be `100000` but they should be uniformly distributed in the range of `0-999`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can't speak for everyone else here but personally I'd start by writing some code.

Comment: std::uniform_int_distribution

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Yes can u give me some idea on this even though i don't need the exact code.

Comment: `std::uniform_int_distribution` from `<random>` since C++11 ?

Comment: yes. but is uniform_int_distribution a member of std???

Comment: Sorry but I'm strongly against _idea welfare_.

Comment: sure if you include <random> header and use -std=c++11 option

Comment: but can't i do this in normal c++???.

Comment: @karlphillip The question you've marked this as a duplicate of is not actually the same (although the same techniques can be applied here); here the OP is interested in a uniform distribution rather than a normal distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write something like the following to populate `R` and `S` quickly using the C++11 STL:

```
#include <numeric>
#include <random>

int main() {
    int R[1000], S[100000];
    std::iota( std::begin( R ), std::end( R ), 0 );
    std::mt19937 engine;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist( 0, 999 );
    std::generate( std::begin( S ), std::end( S ), []{ return dist( engine ); } );
}
```